# Only last row is being inserted into database instead of all the rows? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

```js
$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function () {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // ! -------Gets the input from record row--------

    // * Table variable
    var table = document.getElementById("steptable");
    // ! Since there is an extra th element in the table (the headers) the loop has to start from 1 and not zero
    for (var i = 1, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
      // * iterate through rows
      // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
      ObjType = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Name = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Business = table.rows[i].cells[4].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Project = table.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Deployer_Candidate =
        table.rows[i].cells[6].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
      Description = table.rows[i].cells[7].querySelector(".vcheck").value;

      // * Condition to prevent the other rows from being inserted with the sql insert statement
      if (Name === "") {
        continue;
      }

      console.log(row);
      console.log("ObjType = " + ObjType);
      console.log("Name = " + Name);
      console.log("Business = " + Business);
      console.log("Project = " + Project);
      console.log("Deployer_Candidate = " + Deployer_Candidate);
      console.log("Description = " + Description);
    }

    // * Loop that will run the sql statement for each row in the table
    for (var i = 0; i < selectTkt.length; i++) {
      if (testSelect != "NEW") {
        console.log("response one");
      }

      // * conditional for new tickets being created
      if (testSelect === "NEW") {
        //prettier-ignore
        callDB(
        "INSERT INTO DB(SEQ_NUM, OBJ_TYPE, OBJ_NAME, DEVELOPER_NAME, CHANGE_NUM, DEPLOYER_BUSINESS, DEPLOY_DATETIME, DEPLOYER_PROJECT, DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE , STATUS, TICKET_NUM, CHANGE_ENGINEER, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('"+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1 +"','"+ ObjType +"','" + Name + "','asalem1', '.','" + Business + "', '.', '" + Project + "', '"+ Deployer_Candidate +"', 'existing', 'test', 'test', '"+ Description +"')"
      );
        console.log("response two");
      } else {
      }

      // * condition to break the loop so it does not repeat with the clone rows you can't see
      if ((i = selectTkt.length)) {
        console.log("Brake");
        break;
      }
    }
    // * conditional for updating existing tickets

    // * Forces page reload
    // location.reload();
  }
  // * else display service message
  else {
    console.log("Service Cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
                    <!-- * Main Record Table *-->
                    <div id="steptablecontainer">
                        <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
                            <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border"
                                role="grid">
                                <thead id="recordTableHead">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
                                        <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test"
                                            style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->

                                <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display: none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
                                    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth">
                                            <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record"
                                                value="0">
                                                <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Record intializing *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>

                                        <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
                                        <div id="container">
                                            <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
                                                <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                                                    <option value="TP">TP</option>
                                                    <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                                                    <option value="Package">Package</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </div>


                                        <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
                                            <p>
                                                <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
                                                <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder=""
                                                    class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
                                            </p>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name"
                                                placeholder="" style="display: none;">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
                                                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
                                                    CorporateFinancialServices
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
                                                <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
                                                <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
                                                <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
                                                <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                                                <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
                                                <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
                                                <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck"
                                                placeholder="">
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c
                                                    21000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c
                                                    20000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c
                                                    11000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1
                                                    (wm52a/b/c
                                                    40k/41k/42k)</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Description *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;"
                                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
                            <div class="btn-group2">
                                <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So I have a table where the user can add multiple rows for for inputs. Problem is no matter how many rows are added only the last row information is being used. So instead of returning for example (row 1: 1, 2, 3)
(row 2: 4,5, 6) & (row 3:7, 8, 9) for instance all three rows return 7,8, 9 in the input boxes. Not sure why it doing this because it suppose to loop through the input than insert into the db and than loop again. Instead it looks like it looping through the inputs until it gets to the last row and inserting three times using the last row inputs.

Comment: You're looping to insert *after* your loop over your rows. Each loop over your rows overwrites the variables from the previous row.

Comment: That makes sense now. So do I need to just move the code inside of the variable row loop?

Comment: Maybe? You're also looping over `selectTkt`, but you don't tell us what's in that variable here.

Comment: selectTkt is just the ticket id number for the table. Okay I try what you said and that seem to mostly fix the insert issue but now the table is iterating and looping forever. What condition do I need to stop that from happening? The loop should end when it reaches the last row in the table

Comment: Sounds like `selectTkt` is being modified, such that its length is increasing, thus continuing the loop.

Comment: that makes sense so for the second loop I need to use a different variable I am guessesing? Maybe use the table instead?

Comment: That sounds good. Personally, I would probably save each item in the first loop into an array of objects, thus only keeping the rows you want, then I would loop over that array for your 2nd/Insert loop.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that could look like? I think I understand what you are trying to do with the array but not 100% tbh.